# Set selected tab indicator in Java code

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a `NavigationView` that I want to setup to work along with a `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout`.

A click on an `item` from the `NavigationView` shall :

1. Take the user to the corresponding `fragment`
2. Set the `TabLayout` indicator accordingly

I managed to accomplish the first task using `mViewPager.setCurrentItem()` but I am unable to fix the second one. I tried :

1. To retrieve the `tab` via the `TabLayout` and "select" it :

   ```
   mTabLayout.getTabAt(TAB_POSITION).select();
   ```

   but it was a bust. ([Tab indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025044/set-tab-indicator-position-programatically-in-tablayout-support-library))
2. to call `mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);` after each click on an `item` but same result. ([TabLayout tab selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796710/tablayout-tab-selection)).

**EDIT - code :**

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());
```

.....
.....

```
class PageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
                break;
            case 1:
                mFloatingAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
                break;
            default:
                mFloatingAddButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

How can I manage to tie everything together ?

Answer (score 0):

In the method `setupWithViewPager` of class `TabLayout`, we can see that a callback is set on the view pager :

`viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(this));`

In the class `TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`, here is the method `onPageSelected` :

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
final TabLayout tabLayout = mTabLayoutRef.get();
            if (tabLayout != null && tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() != position) {
                // Select the tab, only updating the indicator if we're not being dragged/settled
                // (since onPageScrolled will handle that).
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position),
                        mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
            }
        }
```

So here we can see that the tablayout should select the good tab when the viewpager changes its content.

Did you call `setupWithViewPager` right after setting the adapter of your `ViewPager` ?

Comment: I do call setupWithViewPager after setting my ViewPager's adapter. Anyway, I tried to do what you said but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to debug to see if this method is really called? Can you show your code?

Comment: The question is not "did you debug" but "did you debug the method `onPageSelected` from `TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`", which is not that obvious.     `mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();`  Using `setupWithPager` already does that for you, as shown in the `onPageSelected` code piece above. Maybe it has consequences setting two times in a row. Try removing those calls in your switch.